# basic question about assigning a variable to a function

Tags: python

Let's say i want to import and use a function func1 from a module func.py as a variable f. I would like to use a short name f so that i don't have to write func.func1 everytime i use it.

The module func.py is

```
    def func1(n):
        print(n+1)
```

and i want to import func

```
    import func
    f = func.func1()
```

Why does it show error in () as "func1 missing 1 required positional argument n"?

```
    import func
    f = func.func1
```

while this doesn't show error?

what is the difference between func.func1 and func.func1() ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want a short name for `func.func1`, so you can call it more easily? Or are you trying to assign the return value of `func.func1()` to a variable? The two snippets are doing entirely different things. Please read [ask].

Comment: Does the function need an argument?

Comment: (Note that you aren't assigning anything to a function here. Assigning to a function is impossible. You're assigning to `f`, not to `func.func1`.)

Comment: In first block, f will hold return value after execution if func1, where as in 2nd block f is just pointing to func1 of func file

Comment: Can you update question with what error you are facing?

Comment: why not use an alias like `import func1 as f from func`

Comment: Your first snippet is trying to run `func1` and assign the result to `f`. I would have to see the error to know what might be causing it. Your second snippet is giving the function a shorter name.

Comment: @Bugbeeb Probably because that's invalid syntax.

Comment: `from func import func1 as f` ?

Answer (score 4):

When you do `f = func.func1()`, you are attempting to *call* `func1`, and bind its return value to `f`. That's not what you intend, and it doesn't work since `func1` expects to be given an argument when it is called. But when you put the `()` on the end, Python sees you making a function call.

When you leave off the `()`, there's no call being done, you're just binding the function to a new name. As has been mentioned in the comments, you can do this in the same step as your import statement, with `from func import func1 as f`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick answer. When you do f = func.func1() you need to pass a variable into the func1(var). In your module it contains a variable called n. N is used to be added to one correct? So when you call the module you also need to give it n or any other variable but make sure its an int. :

```
n = 10
f = func.func1(n)
```

Now it should work fine. All you have to do Is pass a variable inside the parrenthases and it should work.